# Why does this Python Script run much faster on a slower computer?

Tags: python, performance, architecture

I have the following very simple code, that seems to run much faster on a friends computer.

```
count  = 0
maxcount = 100000000

    while(count <= maxcount):
        count += 1
        if(count == 100000000):
            print(count)
```

I would assume that my computer which is newer and has an Intel i7-4720HQ (A Quad-Core at 2.6Ghz, with 3.6Ghz Boost) would perform faster than my friend, which has an Intel i5-3320M (Dual Core at 2.6Ghz, with 3.3Ghz Boost). However if we both run this code at the same time with all other programs closed, his finishes around 20 - 30% faster than mine.

Comment: Benchmarking is more art than science, but fundamentally unless you know what part of the code is doing most of the work, and if this work is CPU-, memory-, or IO-bound you can't really say. So, you should benchmark this code and see.

Comment: Are you both using the same Python versions?

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. It's an interesting observation and a legitimate question in my opinion and according to:  https://stackoverflow.com/tour
edit: and although the accepted answer contains some interesting information i would like to hear more about possible explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using the same operating system and all other factors are controlled, this is likely because your Quad-core processor speeds up to 3.6GHz boost, then reaches thermal limitations and throttles down to 2.6GHz or slower for most of the time it takes to run the program. Whereas your friend's computer is probably able to hold at the 3.3GHz boost clock for longer, meaning overall it still finishes quicker.

On the whole though, with any meaningful application your CPU is significantly faster/more performant than his.

Comment: Also, perhaps worth pointing out, Python won't be able to take advantage of multiple cores in this situation (although the code isn't written that way to begin with).